# How to get the element that has the onClick on a li element that has two span children?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a `<li onClick={x}>` with two `<span>` inside it, when I click and try to get the event target I am getting the `li` or span element depending on where I click, I want to get the `li` element only no matter where i click

```
<li value={1} onClick={this.handleClick}>
  <span> Ones </span>
  <span> Adds 1 point per One </span>
</li>

handleClick(e) {
    console.log(e.target)
}
```

**Expected**: li element

**Results**: li or span depending where I click

Comment: use `e.currentTarget` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get a target the event is attached to, use `e.currentTarget instead`

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
  handleClick = e => {
      console.log(e.currentTarget)
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <li value={1} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <span> Ones </span>
        <span> Adds 1 point per One </span>
      </li>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could solve this is by using CSS.

Since you don't want the children of the `<li>` tag to respond to click events, you could add a style to prevent the children from responding to the events like so:

```
li > * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

This will effectively prevent any child of the `<li>` element from responding to click events.

[Here's a beautiful article by CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/) that explains the `pointer-events` property.